# Check if date in range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to check if the date `2017-09-21 15:30:00 -0400` is in the range of this week.

Here is the code below: I am trying to output true or false but Its not outputting the right answer. In theory this should work.

```
 dateTime = Time.new(2017, 9, 21, 15, 30) => 2017-09-21 15:30:00 -0400 

 Range.new((Date.today), (Date.today+7.days)).include?(dateTime)
```

Basically i am trying to check if the dateTime variable is within this week. But i initialize it using Time.new

Answer (score 5):

It works if you make it a date. Basically you are comparing `Time`s and `Date`s.

```
Range.new(Date.today, Date.today + 7).include?(date_time.to_date)
```

Comment: using `include?` on a `Range` of `Date`s is now deprecated - it's now recommended you use `cover?`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you use `Time` and `Date` together.

If time is important use this:

```
datetime = Time.new(2017, 9, 21, 15, 30)
(Time.now..Time.now + 7.days).include?(datetime)
```

Otherwise use:

```
date = Date.new(2017, 9, 21)
(Date.today..Date.today + 7).include?(date)
```

Note that you can use `7.days` only with included `ActiveSupport`.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote would not check if the date is in this week, even if working, instead it would check if the date is between today and the next seven days?

To check if the date is inside the "week" (as defined from monday to sunday) you could do:

```
date_to_check = Time.utc(2017, 9, 21, 15, 30)
week_start = Time.now.utc.beginning_of_week
week_end = Time.now.utc.end_of_week

date_to_check >= week_start && date_to_check <= week_end
=> true
```

Using utc but you could omit it. On `Time.utc` using `Time.new` instead and then on `week_start & end` omitting `.utc`.